# Listview item value is changed on scrolling in custom cursor adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I am using a listview with cursor adapter.This listview has a imageview in each item when i click on this image view i change the imageview image which is changing properly but when i scroll my list imageview changes to its orignal view.
Note : i am using cursor adapter.(I know about listview recycling and i know to to control value change in simple adapter(model based))
Here is my cursor adapter :

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    spotsImage = (SimpleDraweeView) view.findViewById(R.id.spotsImage);
    ivFavourite = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.favouriteButton);
        ivFavourite.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.PEEP_ID))+"tag"+cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.PEEP_STATUS)));
    spotsTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    followerscount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.distanceTextView);

    spotsTitle.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.PEEP_NAME)));


    Uri uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.PEEP_PROFILE)));
    spotsImage.setImageURI(uri);

     count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.PEEP_FOLLOWER_COUNT));
    if (count > 1){
        followerscount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        followerscount.setText(count+" followers");
    }
    else if (count == 1){
        followerscount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        followerscount.setText(count+" follower");
    }
    else {
        followerscount.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.PEEP_STATUS)) == 1) {
        ivFavourite
                .setImageResource(R.drawable.favourites_tapped);
    } else {
        ivFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.favourites);
    }

    ivFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            String [] Tags = ((String) v.getTag()).split("tag");

            if (Tags[1].equals("1")) {



                    ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.favourites);

            }
            else {

                    ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.favourites_tapped);


            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How ListView's recycling mechanism works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works)

Comment: thanks for reply.I know about listview recycling  and i know how to control value changing in simple adapter(Model based) but i am facing issues with cursor adapter.

Comment: I think the problem is because as the ListView scrolls bindView is called again and when it's recalled it's as if it hasn't been clicked yet so the image goes back to default. You need to find a way to flag that item to know which image to use.

Comment: thats my question how to stop that change.In simple adapters (with model and getview we can change model on item change so this change persists) but how it can be done with a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

As the list scrolls further up/down, the reference held to the position you are looking at which populate the data changes. In other words, when the items are offscreen and need to be rendered back on screen, that list position has already been processed and moved on from so the data will be incorrect.

I would try implementing a custom BaseAdapter and inflate your controls. If you give me a moment I will even do that for you...

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Cursor cursor = null;
    private Context context = null;
    public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        this.context = context;
        if (cursor != null)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            this.cursor = cursor;
        }
    }
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return cursor.getCount();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    //processed at runtime
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistitem);
    spotsImage = (SimpleDraweeView) view.findViewById(R.id.spotsImage);
    ivFavourite = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.favouriteButton);
    ivFavourite.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.PEEP_ID))+"tag"+cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.PEEP_STATUS)));
    spotsTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    followerscount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.distanceTextView);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.PEEP_PROFILE)));
    spotsImage.setImageURI(uri);
    count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.PEEP_FOLLOWER_COUNT));
    if (count > 1){
        followerscount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        followerscount.setText(count+" followers");
    }
    else if (count == 1){
        followerscount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        followerscount.setText(count+" follower");
    }
    else {
        followerscount.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.PEEP_STATUS)) == 1) {
        ivFavourite
                .setImageResource(R.drawable.favourites_tapped);
    } else {
        ivFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.favourites);
    }

    ivFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            String [] Tags = ((String) v.getTag()).split("tag");
            if (Tags[1].equals("1")) {
                ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.favourites);
            }
            else {
                ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.favourites_tapped);
            }
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

}

EDIT:

Oh and ensure you are implementing a method to recycle your bitmaps onPause or you will wind up with OOM exceptions

Or if you are still going to use the CursorAdapter add this method to your SQLiteDatabase:

in your database add the method

```
public void updatePeepStatusById(int id, int newStatus)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWriteableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Constants.PEEP_STATUS, newStatus);
    db.update(PEEPTABLE, cv, PEEPID + " = ?", new String[{Integer.toString(id)}]);

}
```

and then call:
   cursor.requery();
   notifyDataSetChanged();

Everytime you want to change a value

Comment: i am facing issue with cursor adapter. i can have already done it with baseadapter.if you can help with cursor adapter that will be great help.thanks

Comment: Is it possible to use a less encapsulated version (ie more accessible) of the favorited item? As in place an isFavorite check in your Cursor results or even store an arraylist of favorited Ids?

Comment: maintaing a separate array-list of values will be extra work load i guess

Comment: i have however ivFavourite check in my cursor

Comment: problem is that when i do any item favorite how i tell my cursor to make it favorite

Comment: If you want the value to remain favorited upon closing and reopening the application, you could add values as an arraylist to your app settings SharedPreferences or add an extra column to your dataset marking whether or not it is a favourite. Otherwise, even with the extra local values, the favorited items will reset everytime the user opens/closes the application

Comment: i am saving values in tables so when i open or close app changes are maintained.Problem is that changes disappear when i change item at runtime and scroll the list

Comment: at backend (my local tables) changes are adding perfectly

Comment: Check the original post

Comment: brother i am already updating value in my DB and it is updating perfectly.the problem is in adapter.when i scroll listview my value changes back

Comment: Are you calling cursor.requery and notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: cursor.requery is deprecated and notifyDataSetChanged not available for cursor adapter :(

Comment: Add them to your imageview click listener before the end but after the if/else

Comment: cursor.requery is deprecated and notifyDataSetChanged not available for cursor adapter :(

Comment: pardon me utilize the changeCursor(Cursor newCursor) method and repopulate with your database values and then call notifyDataSetChanged() in the adapter

Comment: changing cursor on every click will be a big work load

Comment: Ah that's the only answer I can find... there is no other way to modify a cursor at runtime which is why you may want to consider switching to a baseadapter with a populating class